# Assistance viewing tcptrace output graphs using xplot

Tags: graph, tcp, plot, tcpdump, tcptrace

I am using tcptrace to get connection statistics from a tcpdump file.

```
tcpdump -i any -nn -S -e -s 1514 -v port 4343 -w sink.cap
tcptrace -G sink.cap > tcptrace.txt
```

Tcptrace generates graphs in **.xpl** format. I am having trouble in viewing these graphs using **xplot**. When I run

```
xplot a2b_tput.xpl
xplot a2b_tsg.xpl
```

it throws me the following error messages.

- xplot: invalid data for 2-dim stream
- xplot: empty datastream

> dsriram@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ tcpdump --version; tcptrace -version; xplot -v 
>   tcpdump version 4.0.0 
>   libpcap version 1.0.0 
>   
>   Version: Ostermann's tcptrace -- version 6.6.7 -- Thu Nov  4, 2004 
>     Compiled by 'buildd' at 'Sat Nov  7 22:53:46 UTC 2009' on machine 'rothera' 
>   
>   X Datafile Plotter  V1.19 
>   Copyright (c) ICCE / Karel Kubat 1995. All rights reserved. 
>   Another MegaHard production!

1. I am wondering whether there are any
   compatibility issues.
2. Am I missing some arguments in
   tcptrace/tcpdump/xplot commands to
   get a viewable graph?
3. Are there any other tools available to 
   view.xpl files?

Answer (score 2):

The program you want is **xplot.org**, not **xplot**.
More confusing, the package name of the desired program is **xplot-xplot.org**.

xplot package that you mentioned has nothing to do with tcptrace output graphs (.xpl).

I myself had the same confusion when starting with TCP graphs :).

Answer (score 1):

Check that your xplot files contain valid data (they are basically text files with a sequence of plotting commands). Also try using [jplot](http://tcptrace.org/jPlot/) and see if your plots will load with that.

If you are able to post a link to your .cap file I will happy to take a look

Comment: Thanks rupello. I was able to view the the xplot files using jplot. Even though, they seem to be in a valid format, I am not sure why its not working with xplot. Here is a link to the xplot file. [link](http://codepad.org/sHOD2LQj)

Comment: Here is a link to a .cap file. [Cap file](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B5NH7WdyZzWMM2I2ODEzNmEtNzEwZi00MjMzLWI5MjYtODNlNTc3MDQ3ODcz&hl=en&authkey=CJ7WnMkN)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, turns out there are many xplot implementations. You should use the xplot.org distribution and it works fine. (Or you may use jPlot too of course)